# What is the best way to visualize abstract concepts (algorithm/data structure)?

Tags: visualization, abstraction

What's the best way to "see what is happening" in an algorithm/data structure? If it's something like a binary search I just imagine a bunch of boxes in a row, and throwing half of them out each time. Is there something more powerful that will let us grok something as abstract as an algorithm/data structure?

Clarification: I'm looking for something a little more general. Example: in order to visualize time - some people use a clock in there head but thats slow, whereas a more natural feel would be a globe and if you are trying to get a 'feel' for how an algorithm works you can imagine two objects moving in different directions on that globe.

Comment: different directions? or different rates?

Answer (score 3):

In general, **animations** are excellent for visualizing processes that occur over time, such as the execution of algorithms.

For example, check out these animations: [Animated Sort Algorthms](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/staerk/algorithms/SortAnimation.html)

[Here's an animation](http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/dsrkg/cs210/applets/sortingII/mergeSort/mergeSort.html) that shows how the data structures work on MergeSort.

Now, whether you want to spend time hooking up your algorithm to some kind of animated visualization is a different question!

Comment: Wow - if you start all of the algorithm animations at about the same time, look at Quick Sort go!

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm animation was a big research area in the 1990s.  Marc H. Brown, who was then at the Digital Systems Research Center, did a large amount of interesting work.  The source code to his [Zeus](http://dcvs.elegosoft.com/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/m3/pm3/graphics/animation/zeus/?cvsroot=PM3) animation system is still available, and it would not be hard to get it set up.  I played with Zeus years ago and if I remember correctly it ships with dozens of animations.

They had a couple of 'festivals' where non-experts got together to animate new algorithms.  You can see one of the reports (with still images)  on the [1993 festival](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-RR-126.html).  YouTube has one of their videos [Visualizing Combinatorial Structures](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EIOrizawnsc).

Answer (score 0):

Describing something in terms of another thing is called analogy. You just did it with the binary search being a bunch of boxes. Just play with the student's prior knowledge.

For instance, trees can be thought of linked-lists, with multiple "next" nodes, or they could be explained to the uninitiated as something similar to a hierarchy.

As for concrete methods of explanation, graphs and state machines can be easily visualized with Graphviz. A very basic, directed graph can be expressed very simply:

```
digraph G {
   A->B;
   B->C;
   C->D;
   D->B;
}
```